# httpcontext is null for websockets signalr

Tags: websocket, signalr

I enabled websockets transport for my application using signalr 2.2.2. I could see the websockets transport enabled and applied as expected. At the same time, I could see null for Context.Request.GetHttpContext().ApplicationInstance. Here Context is of type HubCallerContext. Since the connection is established using websocket transport type, then is this applicationinstance null expected? OR am i missing something?

I need to have this httpcontext.current as below. This is working fine when i have longpolling/foreverFrame transport whereas ApplicationInstance is coming as null when i have websocket as transport type.

**System.Web.HttpContext.Current = Context.Request.GetHttpContext().ApplicationInstance.Context**

Any thoughts on the above line of code to get the correct context when i have websockets as transport type for my application.

Thanks